# Org-table and multiple plots

Tags: org-mode, org-table

Is it possible to have several plots related to one Org table? I have noticed that

```
#+plot: ... file:"file1.png"
#+plot: ... file:"file2.png"
#+plot: ... file:"file3.png"
.
.
.
|col1|...|colN|
|....         |
```

doesn't really work. It looks like only the last `#+plot:` directive is considered. Of course, I could write a gnuplot script which is called once and will plot to all those files, but i would prefer to keep it as several distinct plot directives for the reasons of improved readability and a degree of automatism offered by the `#+plot:` directive.

Comment: From looking at the list of options `#+plot` takes, it seems like you cannot specify the table: http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-plot.html#org2ccae51 (esp. not because the second line of `#+plot` is meant for specifying the columns from the table to plot). But maybe I'm wrong, and there is a way.

Comment: Yes, I looked trough the info docs and came to the same conclusion.